# Calling Objective C method with completion handler from Swift3 (completion is IUO?)

Tags: swift, swift3

so I'm finally getting around to doing my Swift3 conversion.  I'm getting MANY of the following errors since we have a legacy codebase that was written in ObjC.

The ObjC definition is here:

```
-(void)getRecommendationHintsWithCompletion:(void(^)(NSArray *recommendationHints, NSError *error))completion;
```

in Swift 2.2, we called it like this:

```
manager.getRecommendationHints { (hints:[AnyObject]!, error: NSError!) in
    //code
})
```

After the swift 3 migrator ran, that line of swift code wasn't changed, but I got the error:

`Cannot convert value of type '([AnyObject]!, NSError!) -> ()' to expected argument type '(([Any]?, Error?) -> Void)!'`

So I tried:

```
manager.getRecommendationHints { (hints:[Any]?, error: Error?) in
    //code
})
```

But I still get:

`Cannot convert value of type '([AnyObject]?, Error?) -> ()' to expected argument type '(([Any]?, Error?) -> Void)!'`

It looks like there's a Implicity Unwrapped Optional on the expected argument, but I'm not sure how to deal with that.

What should I do?  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `Error` instead of `NSError`

```
manager.getRecommendationHints { (hints:[Any]?, error: Error?) in
    //code
}
```

Hopefully this will solve your problem

Comment: Can you please tell me how it is different from my answer?

Comment: I guess we both answered at the same time

Comment: Marking as accepted, but there was an xcode issue where the errors still appeared until I cleaned the project (Cmd-Shift-K) and restarted XCode. :(